# Class 'Laraveldaily\Quickadmin\QuickadminServiceProvider' not found for php artisan in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, panel, laravel-artisan

I want to install [`quickadmin`](http://laraveldaily.com/packages/quickadmin/) to create a quick admin panel, I am using Laravel 5.3 and I have followed the step to install:

1. Create new project

   `composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName --prefer-dist`

2.Install quickadmin

`composer require laraveldaily/quickadmin`

3. Add `Laraveldaily\Quickadmin\QuickadminServiceProvider::class,` to your `\config\app.php` providers after `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,`
4. Configure your .env file with correct database information
5. Run `php artisan quickadmin:install` and fill the required information.

but this error appear

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]              
  Class 'Laraveldaily\Quickadmin\QuickadminServiceProvider' not found
```

What's happend?

Comment: Try `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload` command

Comment: @CanCelik  No, it didnt work

Comment: @RaghavendraN it didn't works

Comment: `php artisan clear-compiled` this could not work if you have wrong permissions. Try to delete manually: `bootstrap/cache/compiled.php`

Answer (score 1):

I think you left one step and that is clear the cache. Please try after clear the cache.

You can run following command after 3rd step :

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

These steps can be followed to install quickadminpanel without any difficulty

1. composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName --prefer-dist
2. cd ProjectName
3. php artisan clear-compiled
4. composer require laraveldaily/quickadmin
5. php artisan clear-compiled
6. Open:

   config/app.php

   insert in the $providers array after Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

   ```
   Laraveldaily\Quickadmin\QuickadminServiceProvider::class,
   ```
7. Open:

   config/app.php

   insert

   ```
   Laraveldaily\Quickadmin\QuickadminServiceProvider::class,
   ```
8. Open:

   app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

   insert after use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   ```

   insert in boot() function

   ```
     Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
   ```
9. Create a database(if you are using something like xampp, create it in phpmyadmin)
10. Modify .env file to add database configurations, db name(the one which you created),
    username(usually root), password
11. php artisan config:cache
12. php artisan config:clear
13. php artisan quickadmin:install
14. enter admin email and password (will be used to login to quickadminpanel everytime, so choose ones you can easily remember)
15. Open:

    App\Http\Kernel.php

    insert in the $routeMiddleware array

    ```
    'role' => \Laraveldaily\Quickadmin\Middleware\HasPermissions::class,
    ```
16. php artisan serve
17. Open browser, url: localhost:8000/admin